# Limit of a Sequence of Polynomial Quotients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**a)** If $q(n) = b_k n^k + b_{k-1} n^{k-1} + \dots + b_1 n + b_0$ is a polynomial in the variable $n$ in the natural numbers with $b_k \neq 0$, show that there exists $N$ in the natural numbers such that $n \geq N$ implies that $q(n) \neq 0$.

**b)** Show that
    \begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_k n^k + a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+a_1 n + a_0}{b_kn^k + b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+b_1n+b_0} = \frac{a_k}{b_k}
\end{align*}
    provided that $b_k \neq 0$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

*Part a)*

Note that $q(n)$ has, at most, $k$ roots. We shall call the largest root $r_{\text{max}}$. Let $N = r_{\text{max}} + 1$. Then $n \geq N$ guarantees that $q(n) \neq 0$.

*Part b)*

We want to show that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ in the natural numbers such that $n > N$ implies that
\begin{align*}
    \Big|\frac{a_k n^k + a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+a_1 n + a_0}{b_kn^k + b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+b_1n+b_0} - \frac{a_k}{b_k}\Big| < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Honestly, I'm at a total loss on this one. The usual strategy is to solve for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$, and use the result to choose our $N$, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case.

Comment: Cannot you just factor the numerator/denominator by $n^k$? $$
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_k n^k + a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+a_1 n + a_0}{b_kn^k + b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+b_1n+b_0} =   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_k + a_{k-1}/n+\dots+a_1/n^{k-1} + a_0/n^k}{b_k + b_{k-1}/n+\dots+b_1/n^{k-1}+b_0/n^k} $$

Comment: For a). The number $N$ should be natural, so we should put for  it, for instance, the smallest natural number bigger than $r_{\operatorname{max}}$.